# A new popup on each function call

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open

I'm trying to write a function that in each call open a new window. Actually it makes the first window and when I call the function again it dont open a new popup, it reload the first one:

```
function openNewWindow(title, url){
    var newWindow = window.open('about:blank', '',
                          'toolbar=0, status=0, scrollbars=1, width=500, height=500');

    var html = '<html><head><title>'+title+'</title></head>'
             + '<body><iframe src="'+url+'" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>'
             + '</body></html>';

    newWindow.document.write(html);
    newWindow.document.close();
}
```

I have tried to store the new window reference in an array, but it dont works as expected. I cant use any library like jQuery. Do you know any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: you should post the code you tried, an array seems to be the easiest way here

Comment: look at the second argument in the window.open method

Comment: Oops, sorry I miss that, very much thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `_blank` as window-name(2nd parameter for `open()`)